# Confusing about logic gates

Tags: logic

Says i have this logic :

> X = (A & B) | ~B

Which can be shorten to :

> X = ~(~A & B)

and then :

> X = A | ~B

so :

> (A & B) | ~B = A | ~B

About this one, i can prove it drawing a truth table, but i still can not shorten the logic.
The guy gave me the shorten logic told me to use [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), but I can't do it through i'm aware of basic De Morgan law

Likewise :

> A AND (A OR B) <=> A

This one i have no idea how it can be shorten like that!

Any explanation is greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Are you asking why it's true that `A | ~B = A | ~B` ?

Comment: @DanZimm sorry, edited, I can prove it's if i draw a truth table, what'm I asking is how can i shorten the logics like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

AND distributes over OR :  $A~\&~(B|C) = (A\&B)~|~(A\&C) $

OR distributes over AND : $A~|~(B\&C) = (A|B)~\&~(A|C)$

---

Your last example :  $A~ \& ~(A | B) = (A|0)~\&~(A|B) = A~|~(0\&B) = A~|~0 = A$

Refer [this](http://www.nayuki.io/page/boolean-algebra-laws) for a list of useful Boolean algebra laws/theorems/proofs

Comment: thanks, how about the first example ?

Comment: simply distribute OR :   $X = (A\&B)~|~\neg B = (A|\neg B)~\&~(B|\neg B ) =  (A|\neg B)~\&~(1 ) =A|\neg B$

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i'll check it out later

Comment: I checked it out, the list is very useful, i'm gonna memorize that, thanks a lot mate

Comment: you're welcome :)